# How to push new HTML elements to an existing parent element in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React app with some dynamically added parents HTML element and each has a button. I need to push a new div element into a selected parent element. I can reach the parent HTML content using `contest`

```
addOptionToContest = (id) => {
    elementsList.forEach(each => {
        if (each.id === id) {
           each.contest.props.children.push(<div>new element</div>)
        }
    })
}
```

**The problem is when I'm pushing a new HTML div element to children, the following error is displaying in the console.**

```
TypeError: Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible
```

I'm sure that "children" is an array, not an Object. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible

Comment: @YoussefKhedher The problem is, I'm trying to push an element to an array. How the error comes with an object error?

Comment: @DavidJohns The reason why you're getting the error is because **you're doing something you're not supposed to**. It's unclear, however, what exactly you're trying to do so it's hard to give you the proper solution. You definitely should **not** be pushing anything to `props.children` and `React` wouldn't even handle this case at all.

Comment: @DavidJohns by the way, `array`s in `JavaScript` are `object`s, so the error message is correct. If you want to add more elements to that component dynamically and you're passing those elements as `props` to another component, then you should lift that logic up to the parent component and pass the updated array so that you don't have to push anything inside child component.